# how to log inside firebase callback when triggered by cron job

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, logging, cron

I have an web-app with a servlet on app-engine

and a cron job that calls that servlet

I how can i see the logs inside the firebase call back? `"onDataChange"`

I see only logs from `"doPost()"`

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MatchingServlet.class.getName());

    @Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    logger.info("in matching-servlet doPost");

    readFromDb();

}

private void readFromDb() {
    firebase.child("users").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            sb.append("elad inside onDataChange. time: "+ System.currentTimeMillis());
            firebase.child("logs").setValue(sb.toString());

            List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
            Iterable<DataSnapshot> children = dataSnapshot.getChildren();

            System.out.println("children = " + children);
            logger.info("children = " + children);
            for (DataSnapshot ds : children) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase callbacks are Async, so your readFromDB is supposed to register a listener and just keep waiting for Firebase to send updates, unfortunately your thread is killed as soon as the task is over. This is a big problem for GAE since instances are being created and destroyed all over, so getting a constant connection to Firebase servers is not trivial.

In order to work with Firebase callbacks you are going to have to setup a [resident instance](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/an-overview-of-app-engine#scaling_types_and_instance_classes) using Services (formerly known as Modules)

Comment: and if i have a resident instance, how can i log inside the callback method? still the logs from there don't appear in the console

Comment: Log should work exactly the same there as it does on a standard instance. HEADS UP: default logger level is WARN so everything below that level (eg the INFO messages you are login) wont show up

Comment: i already changed level to INFO, and no log in the callback is printed to the log. Only if I save the log to firebase "logs" child, it can be written and read later. How come?